# How can I see dumps of wholе HTTP packets?

Tags: networking, monitoring, http

I need to see whole HTTP packets sent and recieved by an application for debugging purposes. How can this be done in command-line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use tcpdump.

`tcpdump -w httpdebug.pcap -i eth0 port 80` will sniff all packets heading to or from port 80 on the eth0 interface and output them to `httpdebug.pcap`, which you can then read at your leisure, either with tcpdump again (with multiple `-x` options, refer to the tcpdump manpage ) in console if you're feeling masochistic, or with [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

I really can't recommend the latter highly enough, as it will let you sort out packets and follow the exact stream you want to see.

Comment: Be sure to add -s0 so you get the entire packet.  It's usually truncated by default.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to use command line for this there is [tcpflow](http://www.circlemud.org/~jelson/software/tcpflow/). It saves TCP streams to different files. The HTTP request and responses will be stored separately.

```
tcpflow -i wlan0 tcp port 80
```

If you can use GUI try [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). You can right click any packet and pick "Follow TCP stream".